How would i use gesturehandler that inside flatlist in react native?
I have a gesture handler thats inside flatlist. Seems like when i do this, i am unable to scroll. How would i make it so that it shoudl be able to scroll? Flatlist gesture is vertically scrolled and the gesture is on the x axis.  Im using reanimated v3
 <Animated.FlatList
          ref={flatListRef}
data={cards}
render={ ()=> <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <TableRow flatListRef={flatListRef} />
            <TableRow
              flatListRef={flatListRef}
            />
            <TableRow flatListRef={flatListRef} />
            <TableRow
              flatListRef={flatListRef}
            />
            <TableRow flatListRef={flatListRef} />
          </View>

const TableRow.= ({flatListRef}) => {
return <GestureHandlerRootView>
      <GestureDetector gesture={Gesture.Race([pan, flatListRef])}>
}

i know u cant use ref inside simutaneous or RAce. But how would i achieve this?
